# Read in the contents of a tab delimited text file and save into a single array in C

Tags: c, arrays, text-files

I am trying to read in the contents of a file using command line arguments to read the file and then store all contents of the file into a single array.

Keep in the mind, the file being read in is actually a matrix with the first row being an integer value designating the square size of the matrix and the following rows and columns being the matrix.

so far I have been able to dynamically allocate memory and then read the contents of the file using fgets.  I am kind of stumped when it comes to storing the contents into a single array to access later.  I tried using a double variable to hold the parsed contents of the 2nd while loop but when printed to the terminal it only gave me the last variable in the file.

I have attempted using strdup to make a copy of the string but am running into an error that says a value of type char cannot be stored in an entity of type char

here is my code.

If someone could help me, I would be very grateful.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){     //char **argv will be used to read the input file

    int i,j,k,l,m,nn;
    long size;
    double mat;
    char *buff;
    char n[100];
    char *file = argv[1];
    long len =0;
    int h =0;

    FILE *output;                   // need to declare the output file

    FILE *f =fopen(file, "rb+");    //utilize argv to read in file, will read file in as binary file to obtain ASCII
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);         //Want to determine the size of the file to create a buffer 
    size = ftell(f);                //Will seek to the end of the file, declare that position as the size
    rewind(f);                      //Will rewind to the beginning of the file
    buff = (char *)malloc(size);    //Declare the buffer size from fseek

    //Will read in and print out the contents of the file using fgets and printf

    while(fgets(buff,size - 1,f) != NULL){
        printf( "%s\n", buff);

    }
    rewind(f);
    while(fscanf(f, "%lf", &mat) ==1){
        buff[h] = _strdup(n);
        h++;
    }

    printf("matrix stored is %c\n",mat);
```

Comment: You know you can't store an entire matrix in a single `double` variable?

Comment: `strtok()` and `strtod()` are your friends.

Comment: Over-complicated, and it won't work anyway :(  I just wanted to make sure the indentation was correct ;)  SUGGESTION: 1) Read about [strtok()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), 2) Open the file and read a line at a time in a simple loop (like you're doing now), 3) Simply parse the items in the line with strtok, and read them into your array.  4) Close the file when done.  5) Remember - you'll also need a loop to *print* the array (you can't just do it with a simple "printf()").  Forget about strdup(), forget about ftell()/rewind(), etc - you can eliminate 2/3 of your code :)

Comment: There are a number of ways to do it. Read a line at a time with `fgets` and then use `strtod` (utilizing the `*endptr` parameter) and scanning forward with either a simple loop or `strchr` to the next `','` (or separator char), add `1` to the pointer, and repeat. Alternatively *tokenize* the line with `strtok` with `",\n"` as your delimiters calling `strtod` on the return from `strtok` within a loop. (you can also use `sscanf` with the `%n` specifier to update an offset to do the same thing.) Post a copy of the first 3 or so lines of your data file.

Comment: Also, what do you expect `printf("matrix stored is %c\n",mat);` to print? (hint `"%c"` will at most print 1-char, and is incompatible with a `double mat;` -- invoking *Undefined Behavior*)

Comment: `size = ftell(f);` reports the file length. `while(fgets(buff,size - 1,f) != NULL)` only reads a _line_.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
/*
 * EXAMPLE FILE:
 *   3,3
 *   1,2,3
 *   4,5,6
 *   7,8,9
 *
 * EXAMPLE OUTPUT:
 *   #/rows=3, #/columns=3
 *   1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000
 *   4.000000, 5.000000, 6.000000
 *   7.000000, 8.000000, 9.000000
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXLINE 100
#define DELIMITER ","

void print_matrix (int nrows, int ncols, double **mat) {
  int i, j;
  printf("#/rows=%d, #/columns=%d\n", nrows, ncols);
  for (i=0; i < nrows; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < ncols-1; j++) {
      printf("%lf, ", mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("%lf\n", mat[i][j]);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  FILE *fp = NULL;
  int iret = 1, n = 0, nrows, ncols;
  double **mat, d;
  char *s, line[MAXLINE], *endptr;
  int i, j;

  /* Read .csv filepath from cmd-line */
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf ("USAGE: app <fname>\n");
    goto the_end;
  }

  /* Open file */
  if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {
    printf ("File open(%s) failed: errno= %d\n",
      argv[1], errno);
    goto the_end;
  }

  /* Read matrix dimensions */
  iret = fscanf(fp, "%d,%d", &ncols, &nrows);
  if (iret != 2) {
    printf ("Unable to read file dimensions, iret= %d, expected 2\n",
      iret);
    goto the_end;
  }

  /* Flush the extraneous newline left in the read buffer after fscanf()... */
  fgetc(fp);

  /* Allocate space for our matrix */
  mat = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *)*nrows);
  if (!mat) {
    printf ("Memory allocation error @matrix, errno=%d: exiting progam\n",
      errno);
    goto the_end;
  }
  for (i=0; i < nrows; i++) {
    mat[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*ncols);
    if (!mat[i]) {
      printf ("Memory allocation error @matrix[%d], errno=%d: exiting progam\n",
        i,  errno);
      goto the_end;
    }
  }

  /* Populate the matrix */
  for (i=0; i < nrows; i++) {
    ++n;
    s = fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp);
    if (s == NULL) {
      printf ("fgets read error, line %d, errno=%d: exiting program\n",
        n, errno);
      goto the_end;
    }
    s = strtok(line, DELIMITER);
    for (j=0; j < ncols; j++) {
      d = strtod(s, &endptr);
      if (s == endptr) {
        printf ("strtod(%s) conversion error, errno %d: exiting program\n",
          s, errno);
        goto the_end;
      }
      mat[i][j] = d;
      s = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);
    }
  }

  /* Print the matrix */
  print_matrix (nrows, ncols, mat);

  /* Set "OK" status */
  iret = 0;

the_end:
  if (fp)
    fclose(fp);
  printf("Done: status=%d (%s)\n",
    iret,
    (iret == 0) ? "Status: OK" : "Status: FAIL");
  return iret;
}
```

Comment: Nice example but I think the `free`s are missing.

Comment: I get an error when I try to run your code, it says a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double *" this occurs on line 60

Comment: Sorry - it compiled and ran fine for me (GCC, Ubuntu Bionic Beaver).  Please try this `mat[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*ncols);`  "stdlib.h" should be the correct header for "malloc()".  The source file suffix should be ".c" (to ensure compiling as "C", not C++).  'Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome!  Quick question though, where you are allocating memory for the matrix, why are the rows done with double ** and the columns double *?  does doing a double pointer evaluate the matrix in a particular space?

Comment: Yes.  The way C works, a 2-d array like `a[][]` is equivalent to an array of pointers.  Hence the need to malloc both 1) the 2-D array[][], as well as 2) each row in the array.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I have another question regarding the population of the matrix.  For the s = fgets and s = strtok.  They both exist within the same for loop and I'm getting nptr!=NULL errors when I run code similar to this in a windows command line.  when I change s = fgets and then t = strtok I get a matrix of zeroes and when I change s = strtok to t = strtok in the second for loop i get odd floating point values.  Specifically rows of 0's, 1's, 12's and -55's.   I'm a little confused as to what is happening there.

Comment: It sounds like you're using different code ;)  Hint: the first new call to strtok() will pass string "s"; subsequent calls for the next tokens in the same string will pass NULL.  There's another, "newer" function that uses an "endptr *" instead: [strtok_r()](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3p-strtok/).